# Differences between /dev and /exec + managing versions

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications

I have a few questions concerning publishing versions of script.

1. What are the detailed differences between `/exec` and `/dev` versions of script?
2. What exactly happens if I save a version of the script, then publish it, and then make some changes in the code:

   - do they affect a `/exec` version of published script if I do not create next version before making these changes?
3. I have a published version of the script, then I publish another one with newer version, then I make some changes in the code, but they seem to affect the oldest published version too, is that possible or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want your script to be able to get the project version that it is running within then please go "star" @Edo 's corresponding [feature request (#1369)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1369).  Your star equals a vote for this feature.  (The request is in the official Apps-Script issue tracker, [according](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing-features) to the official Google Apps Script Support page.)

Answer (score 5):

a. /exec points are the currently deployed "production" version of your app. This will point to a named version under File -> Manage Versions. This way you can continue to test after you snap shotted a version and published it without breaking anybody. /dev points to the most current copy of the code... you dont have to save versions to test any changes. You can only have ONE version of your application published.

[image: current published version]

b. Per point above, any changes you make without publishing that version (you have to save a new version first) will NOT affect /exec. But this will show up right away in /dev

c. I don't understand this - how do you mean "seem to affect the oldest published version too"? You can't access the oldest published version. There is only one published version (/exec) and the current state of the code (/dev).

Comment: Well, I have 2 links for my script:
https://sites.google.com/a/macros/tarendo.pl/s/"key1"/exec
https://sites.google.com/a/macros/tarendo.pl/s/"key2"/exec
They were published with different versions of the script and they both seem to work, is that normal behavior?
What is more, when I change my script it seems to affect both exec's and I don't know if it is a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmmn, that is not normally possible. The only way this is possible is if you have a Script Library project and its included in both those web apps (with different keys) and its included in "Development Mode" and you are editing the Script Library. That would affect two different services that are published with two different keys.

Comment: Thanks, a lot for your answer. In fact I've a library included in my script and it's in the "Development Mode" mode, but I did not have an idea that it would cause such a strange behavior. When I turn off the "Development Mode" it would get back to standard behavior?

Comment: That's correct - if you turn off Development mode, you'l get to pick a specific published static version of the library that the web app will run against. Let me know if that makes sense and works as described.